# Are there any methods for listing all current keyboard shortcuts a system recognizes?

Tags: macos, keyboard, keybindings

I've been spending some time with tools like BetterTouchTool, Hammerspoon, Alfred, etc. and I've found different uses for each. However I'm having a hard time keeping everything straight, particularly tracking conflicting keyboard shortcuts between default app settings, system level commands, etc.

Is there a way to generate a complete, system-wide list of key commands that would indicate any conflicts and/or where a particular command is set?

Xcode for instance will show conflicts with system settings - is there a way to do this globally?

[image]